# IOError opening jpg in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, reportlab

My program prompts the user to select files (via a PyQT4 MainWindow) and then generates a pdf report in ReportLab.

I'm getting an IOError on one of the 2 images I'm trying to include. Both images are in the directory where every other file I'm using is. I also tried it loading the other image as both images, no error. I tried it using a different image that's outside the directory - works fine. I suspected that maybe the file size is too big of the problem image, so I went from a 450kB image to a 45 kB image. Still no dice.

Problem code:

```
#from the code for the Compiled Window - this is how I acquire the images
...
def logo_pic(self):
    self.Logo_picture = unicode(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName())
    self.LogoLabel.setText(self.Logo_picture) #this shows the user the path of the file they selected

def setup_pic(self):
    self.setup_picture = unicode(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName())
    self.SetupLabel.setText(self.setup_picture) 
...

#take the file path and turn it into a workable file name
setup_pic_title_index = str(cw.setup_picture).rfind('/') + 1
setup_pic_title = cw.setup_picture[setup_pic_title_index:]
Logo_picture_title_index = str(cw.Logo_picture).rfind('/') + 1
Logo_picture_title = cw.Logo_picture[Logo_picture_title_index:]

#this is where the image itself is pulled and scaled appropriately for the ReportLab document, and added to the list of items to include
elements.append(get_image('./' + Logo_picture_title, width = 9*inch))
elements.append(get_image('./' + setup_pic_title, width = 8*inch))
```

Here's the Errors I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
File "C:/Users/moi/etc", line 367, in <module>
    elements.append(get_image('./' + setup_pic_title, width = 8*inch))
File "C:/Users/moi/etc", line 233, in get_image
    img = utils.ImageReader(path)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 585, in __init__
annotateException('\nfileName=%r identity=%s'%(fileName,self.identity()))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 549, in __init__
self.fp = open_for_read(fileName,'b')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py", line 452, in open_for_read
raise IOError('Cannot open resource "%s"' % name)

IOError: Cannot open resource "./DSCN2223.JPG"
fileName=u'./DSCN2223.JPG' identity=[ImageReader@0x70b1870 filename=u'./DSCN2223.JPG']
```

I included the code for the logo and the setup picture - the info is basically identical. Also, it works with a different .jpg file outside of the directory.

Comment: where is `./DSCN2223.JPG`?

Comment: In the same directory as the other 8 files I have the user select. And in the same directory as the logo jpg.

Comment: and you have no problems opening any of the others?

Comment: No. I can also use the logo for both files and that works.

Comment: Can you open it in isolation? That is, fire up the python interpreter and running very simplified code?

Comment: I just tried it - no.

Comment: I looked at reportlab\lib\utils.py and its horribly bad. It catches all exceptions and raises a generic IOError with all useful info removed. I'd hack that file and wrap the open in open_for_read_by_name with my own exception handler that wrote out the real problem. It could be something like you've got the image open in another program and have a sharing violation. It would be nice to have the actual real exception which would tell you so!

Comment: INORITE? Somehow it just stopped raising that issue and now I've got a totally different, unrelated problem. Blargh. It's like a magical cluster right now. Thanks for trying!

Comment: I think I figured it out. I'm having a path problem. The logo isn't giving me a problem because that file with that name is available in the other place I tried to pull it from, so I was falsely getting the impression that it was working when it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem I was having was traced back to not using the full pathname. To fix this problem, I saved a variable NAMED pathname:

```
document_title_index = str(first_Fname).rfind('/') + 1 #find the last / and add 1
document_title = first_Fname[document_title_index: len(first_Fname)-4] #uses the index to grab the string that's affiliated with the first data file for naming the report
pathname = first_Fname[0:document_title_index] # grabs the pathname part to place new files correctly
```

Then, when I was saving my figures, I used the pathname to put them in the right place - with the source data for the reports INSTEAD of where it would have ended up before, with the .py file itself:

```
plt.savefig(pathname + figname + '.jpg', dpi = 100)  #save plots to the same place as the first data file
```